# What is the efficient way to show next binary having n no of 1?

Tags: binary

I need this series of data where n = 4.

> 111100
>   111010
>   111001
>   110110
>   110101
>   110011
>   101110
>   101101
>   101011
>   100111
>   011110
>   011101
>   011011
>   010111
>   001111

All of the above number contains 4 no's of 1

I try to solve problem with hamming weight. But, for a larger no, it is time consuming.

Is there any mathematics by which i can get next number which have n no of 1?

Comment: Where is $010111$?

Comment: This is [A014312](https://oeis.org/A014312) on oeis.  They don't reference a simpler form for the sequence, which of course does not prove that there isn't one (but which is not a good sign).

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357124/find-next-number-with-specific-hamming-weight) is a relevant link.